# openssl how to generate CSR with S/MIME Capabilities

Tags: linux, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-signing-request

what req_extensions should I pass to openssl to include "**S/MIME Capabilities**" into my CSR?

Please see example openssl s_client outpout below from installed certificate.

I aware of

"X509v3 extensions" - keyUsage= attribute.

and

"X509v3 Extended Key Usage" - extendedKeyUsage= attribute.

**openssl s_client** output:

```
X509v3 extensions:
    X509v3 Key Usage: critical
        Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment

    S/MIME Capabilities: 
        050...{some binary like data}

    X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
        TLS Web Server Authentication
```

P.S.
Looks like for MS
this is -SmimeCapabilities attribute:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps

Answer (score 0):

regarding S/MIME Capabilities:

answer found here: http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/SMIME-Capabilities-encoding-in-openssl-cnf-td24845.html

*path how to inculde SMIME-CAPS is:
[ req ] section -> req_extensions = req_ext -> [ req_ext ] section -> SMIME-CAPS         = ASN1:SEQUENCE:smime_seq

```
[ req_ext ]
SMIME-CAPS         = ASN1:SEQUENCE:smime_seq
[ smime_seq ]
capabilityID.0 = OID:sha1
capabilityID.1 = OID:sha256
capabilityID.2 = OID:sha1WithRSA
capabilityID.3 = OID:aes-256-ecb
capabilityID.4 = OID:aes-256-cbc
capabilityID.5 = OID:aes-256-ofb
capabilityID.6 = OID:aes-128-ecb
capabilityID.7 = OID:aes-128-cbc
capabilityID.8 = OID:aes-128-ecb
```

**The additional question is**:

How to read SMIME capability from certificate installed on server and transform it to OIDs like aes-128-ecb etc ?

with 'openssl s_client -connect ..' or any other.